# Is it possible to pop a certain element off the standard library's LinkedList?

Tags: linked-list, rust

Is it possible to pop a certain element off the standard library's [`LinkedList`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html)? Could it be possible to reorder a linked list so the selected element appears at the end and then you pop it off?

Answer (score 3):

Sure. It requires O(n) time though, so it's not a **good** idea:

```
use std::collections::LinkedList;

fn main() {
    let mut list: LinkedList<i32> = (1..10).collect();

    let mut tail = list.split_off(5);

    let x = list.pop_back();
    let y = tail.pop_front();

    list.append(&mut tail);

    println!("({:?}, {:?})", x, y); // (Some(5), Some(6))
    println!("{:?}", list);         // [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8, 9]
}
```

Use [`split_off`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.split_off) to create two lists. This takes O(n) time to walk through the list to the requested node. This also panics if the index is invalid.

You can then either take the tail of the first list ([`pop_back`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.pop_back)) or the head of the second list ([`pop_front`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.pop_front)). You can then splice the lists back together with [`append`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.append). These all work on O(1) time.